# What is the meaning of this Eclipse icon?

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I really don't know which is the meaning of this icon. I'm using Eclipse Luna, and unfortunately I didn't find the meaning in their [help](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm). I'm working on a Android app with NDK and I've noticed the icon after  removed the `obj/` folder from my git tracking.

[image]

Can you tell me which is the meaning of that icon, ad what can I do in order to fix my problem/

So far, it seam that the application is running fine, but I'm worried anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This image describes all the possible states:

**Check the each file names. They explains there own current state.**

[image]

Basically the esteric (*) refers to **staged** - The resource has changes which are added to the index. Not that adding to the index is possible at the moment only on the commit dialog on the context menu of a resource.

**Solution:**

As this **obj** folder was previously **tracked**, that's why in spite of removing from the the git tracking it is removed from your local repo not from the remote repository. So what you can do is just clear the cache by using the following command and restage your project.

```
git rm --cached
```

**Please a take backup of your project to be safe.**

For detail: Check this [doc](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/State).

Answer (score 6):

That means the files are under version control. 
For example svn, git etc. The files are changed and not commited.

If you do a right click on a file or the project itselfs you should see an entry like `SVN` or `GIT` etc.
Here you have the possibility to commit the changed data and the icon will dissapear.

If there is no need to observe these files via version control you can `ignore` them. How to configure that depends on the version control system you are using. In git you can do that via `Team->ignore`
or via `TortoiseGit` outside `TortoiseGit->Delete and add to ignore list`

Answer (score 2):

This means that you have yet to Commit Changes on the version control you are using. Git or SVN